# Implement time window in procedures in Oracle

Tags: oracle

## The procedure is unable to execute,I get an invalid error statement

```
create or replace procedure test
AS
declare Current_Time1 varchar(10);
begin

  SELECT to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH:MI.AM') INTO Current_Time1 FROM DUAL

  IF(Current_Time1 BETWEEN '09:00.AM' AND '05:00.PM')THEN
 
    dbms_output.put_line (Current_time1);

  ELSE 

    dbms_output.put_line ('Unable to insert');

  END IF;

end;
```

Comment: It should be useful to specify what kind of error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE                                                                         
-------------------                                                             
20.03.2014 18:17:13                                                             

SQL> create or replace procedure test
  2  AS
  3  begin
  4  
  5    IF sysdate between trunc(sysdate,'DD')+interval '9' hour
  6        and trunc(sysdate,'DD')+interval '17' hour
  7    THEN
  8  
  9       dbms_output.put_line(sysdate);
 10  
 11    ELSE
 12  
 13      dbms_output.put_line ('Unable to insert');
 14  
 15    END IF;
 16  
 17  end;
 18  /


SQL> exec test
Unable to insert                                                                


SQL> create or replace procedure test
  2  AS
  3  begin
  4  
  5    IF sysdate between trunc(sysdate,'DD')+interval '9' hour
  6        and trunc(sysdate,'DD')+interval '19' hour
  7    THEN
  8  
  9       dbms_output.put_line(sysdate);
 10  
 11    ELSE
 12  
 13      dbms_output.put_line ('Unable to insert');
 14  
 15    END IF;
 16  
 17  end;
 18  /

SQL> exec test
20.03.2014 18:18:01
```

P.S.

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) + interval '9' hour + interval '15' minute from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)+INTE                                                             
-------------------                                                             
21.03.2014 09:15:00                                                             

SQL> select trunc(sysdate) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(9.25,'HOUR') from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)+NUMT                                                             
-------------------                                                             
21.03.2014 09:15:00                                                             

SQL> select trunc(sysdate) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(9,'HOUR')+NUMTODSINTERVAL(15,'MINUTE') from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)+NUMT                                                             
-------------------                                                             
21.03.2014 09:15:00
```

Comment: How would i make the changes the test between 9:15 and 5:59 pm...am i am trying but no success.

Comment: See Interval Literals and NUMTODSINTERVAL in Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221. I added an example to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "declare" from the variable declaration. Also put a ";" in the end of the select statement.